# Date expressions is crashing

Tags: c#, html, datetime, razor, datetimepicker

I reformatted my date in order to remove the time from the date but, now my date function is crashing because the date is 'null'.  I have not selected a date yet.  I am trying to go into the form to select a date but I can't because if won't allow me.

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <strong>Admission Date: </strong>
         <input type="date" id="date-of-screening1" name="AdmDate1" value="@Admission1.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")"></td>
      <td>
         <strong>Discharge Date: </strong>
         <input type="date" id="date-of-screening2" name="DisDate1" value="@Discharge1.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")">
      </td> 
</table>
```

I'm having another date issue. My date was not saving so I decided to change the format but, now I'm getting an error.

Here is the error:

Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'DateAdministered' does not exist in the current context

Here is my code:

```
<td><strong>Date Aministered:</strong><input type="date" id="date-of-screening" name="DateAdministered" value="@(DateAdministered !=null ? DateAministered.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : "01/01/2000")"></td>
```

I have checked the name of the field to make sure it matches what's in the table and it does.  I'm not sure what the problem may be.

Comment: What are the types of `Admission1` and `Discharge1`? What do you mean by crashing? Do you get any exception or error message?

Comment: You're not closing your `<tr>`.

Comment: how about this.. can you post the code that was working ..? so that we can see what it was you were doing prior.. also show all code so that we won't make assumptions on what you have or have not left out of your code also look into using `'` single quotes wrapped inside of double quotes.. or use `HTML Binding`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have null in your Admission1 variable. So you can't call ToString on it. You either have to make sure it is not null (i.e. to set some sort of default date to it) or make a condition like this:

```
value="@(Admission1 != null ? Admission1.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : "01/01/2000")"
```

Same for the other variable ...

Comment: Now I'm getting the following error:The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.                                                                                        It's happening on this line of code:                                      db.Execute(SQLUPDATE, Admission1, Discharge1, LOC1, Program1, Notes, Admission2, Discharge2, LOC2, Program2, Notes2, SSId);

Comment: That's possibly unrelated to this question. You should create new SO question and share the relevant server side code there.